# Get specific attribute using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract attribute from within a HTML tag using beautifulsoup. How to do it ?

For Example:

```
<div class="search-pagination-top clearfix  mtop ">
                                            <div class="row"><div class="col-l-4 mtop pagination-number" tabindex="0"
aria-label="Page 1 of 15 "><div>Page <b>1</b> of <b>15</b> </div></div>
```

How do I get text from "aria-label" attribute ?

I tried using select() but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the attribute value just like a dictionary. Using the key `aria-label`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="search-pagination-top clearfix  mtop ">
                                            <div class="row"><div class="col-l-4 mtop pagination-number" tabindex="0"
aria-label="Page 1 of 15 "><div>Page <b>1</b> of <b>15</b> </div></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print( soup.find("div", class_="col-l-4 mtop pagination-number")["aria-label"] )
```

**Output:**

```
Page 1 of 15
```